# Why Levi-Civita term signal the breaking of parity and time reversal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, chern-simons-theory, cpt-symmetry

For example, referring to Zee's QFT book, in Chern-Simons matter theory, after writing a term 
$$\gamma {\varepsilon ^{\mu \nu \lambda }}{a_\mu }{\partial _\nu}{a_\lambda }$$
he said

> *The appearance of $ε_{μνλ}$ signals the violation of parity P and time reversal invariance T , something we already know.*

However I didn't found anyplace he explained this. What's the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the parity operation is

$P: (t,x) \rightarrow (t',x') = (t,-x)$

lets see how this effects this term...

$\epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda} a_\mu \partial_\nu a_\lambda = \epsilon^{\mu 0 \lambda} a_\mu \partial_0 a_\lambda + \epsilon^{\mu j \lambda} a_\mu \partial_j a_\lambda$

$=\epsilon^{\mu 0 \lambda} a_\mu \partial'_0 a_\lambda - \epsilon^{\mu j \lambda} a_\mu \partial'_j a_\lambda$

is there anyway via re-arranging the second terms indices or relabeling dummy indices such that you can re-express the last equality as

$=\epsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda} a_\mu \partial'_\nu a_\lambda$   ?

if not, then this term is not symmetric to the parity operation.  You can try to do the same with T.

Comment: why in your comment the parity operation doesn't change fields?

Comment: it would but there are two instances of $a$ so any change is $(-1)^2 = 1$ no change...good question though I should have made that explicit.

Comment: Also the Levi-Civita tensor should change under these discrete transformations, as a tensor density. In $d=1+1$ and $d=3+1$, the dimensionality of the OP's world and the real world respectively, the Levi-Civita tensor changes as $\varepsilon\rightarrow -\varepsilon$ under parity and time-reversal transformations, since $\det P = \det T = -1$. However, an overall sign will not change your final conclusion - that the term in question violates parity and time-reversal symmetries.